# Android gesture onScroll() and onScale() mix together

Tags: android, scroll, gesture, pinchzoom

I want to catch two gestures, the first one is a scroll, fire a movement of a `view`.
The second gesture is a pinch-in, fire `startActivityForResult` on different `Activity`.
My problem that `onScroll(...)` and `onScale(...)` are called alternatively, and I didn't found a consistency, particularly the gesture can begin with `onScroll` or `onScale`.
example of a gesture:

```
onDown
onScroll
onScaleBegin
onScale
onScroll
onScale
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19545542/1869297) assume to manage the problem, but there the pinch lead to continuous changing of the image, using a `matrix`, while I'm looking for a single response (jump to different activity).
In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18551840/1869297) post they suggested a practice to prevent `onScroll(...)` to be called after `onScale(...)` was called, but this doesn't solves the case that `onScroll(...)` called before `onScale(...)`.

I thought to create a small delay before firing the onScroll response, enable the `onScale(...)` a chance to be called. But this is bad idea of course.

**EDIT:**  another option is to use `ACTION_MOVE` in `onTouchEvent(...)` instead of `override` `onScroll(...)`.
The problem is that now how would I know if the **firsts** `ACTION_MOVE` should be interpret as a scroll gesture, hence move the view up\down,
or as pointers movement before `onScroll(...)` will be called, and then I moved the view without any reason.

Comment: why do you need onScroll?

Comment: @pskink even if I use `ACTION_MOVE` in `onTouchEvent(...)` instead of `onScroll(...)` how would I know if the **firsts** `ACTION_MOVE` should be interpret as a scroll gesture, hence move the view up\down,  or as pointers movement before `onScroll(...)` will be called, and then I moved the view without any reason.

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633545/android-imageview-scaling-and-translating-issue how i combined together move/scale/rotate gestures

Comment: @pskink can you please highlight the main idea in your solution that solves the arrangement issue between `onMove(...)` and `onScale(...)` . Thanks!

Comment: the main idea is to transform the Matrix in the gestures' callbacks and using that Matrix for Bitmap drawing

Comment: @pskink and it's wise to use a Matrix although I'm not handling any image changes?

Comment: ok so what do you need scale/move for?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50861/discussion-between-user1869297-and-pskink)